# Можно ли у разделов в кастомайзере сделать подразделы (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Можно ли у разделов в кастомайзере сделать подразделы?

[image: разделы кастомайзера]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Вам нужны [Panels](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#panels).

Пример из документации:

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'menus', array(
  'title' => __( 'Menus' ),
  'description' => $description, // Include html tags such as <p>.
  'priority' => 160, // Mixed with top-level-section hierarchy.
) );
$wp_customize->add_section( $section_id , array(
  'title' => $menu->name,
  'panel' => 'menus',
) );
```